# Python upload a file to AWS S3 with existing presign URL from another account

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-transfer

I have a pre sign URL from a client, I want to store the file in my AWS S3 bucket

```
from requests import get
resp = get(url=[Presign URL], timeout=9000)
s3_client.upload_fileobj(resp.content, "my-bucket", "xyz/abc/hmm.avro")
```

with this code, I am getting the below error

```
{ValueError}Fileobj must implement read
```

I there a way to directly move the file

Comment: You could instead use `s3_client.put_object(Bucket="my-bucket", Key="xyz/abc/hmm.avro", Body=resp.content.encode())`

Answer (score 3):

The error you are encountering is because the `upload_fileobj` method of the S3 client in boto3 is expecting a file-like object that has a `read` method. But the content attribute of the response object returned by `requests.get` is bytes.

you can use `io.BytesIO` to create a file-like object from the bytes:

```
import io
import boto3
from requests import get

presigned_url = "[Presign URL]"
response = get(url=presigned_url, timeout=9000)

if response.status_code == 200:
    file_like_object = io.BytesIO(response.content)
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    s3_client.upload_fileobj(file_like_object, "my-bucket", "xyz/abc/hmm.avro")
else:
    print("Failed to fetch the file")
```

Read [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html) for more info regarding files upload